Electron.NET not using port number in loadURL
I'm trying to use Electron.NET to open my asp.net core application like a desktop app.  I have the following in my Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);

...

string url = "http://localhost:5001";
await app.StartAsync();

var browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions
{
    Width = 1152,
    Height = 940,
    Show = false
}, url);

await browserWindow.WebContents.Session.ClearCacheAsync();

browserWindow.OnReadyToShow += () => browserWindow.Show();
browserWindow.SetTitle("My Application");

app.WaitForShutdown();

When the app starts, it is running on port 5001 as expected.  I can load it in a browser.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5001

However, after the app starts, Electron gives an error on CreateWindowAsync:
SocketIOClient.ConnectionException: Cannot connect to server 'http://localhost/'
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SocketIOClient.SocketIO.ConnectAsync()
   at ElectronNET.API.SocketIoFacade.Connect()
   at ElectronNET.API.BridgeConnector.get_Socket()
   at ElectronNET.API.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(BrowserWindowOptions options, String loadUrl)

Why is it trying to load 'http://localhost/' and not 'http://localhost:5001/'?  I gave the correct url as the loadUrl parameter in the call to CreateWindowAsync.

The is the value of loadUrl?  Does it contain the port 5001?

Yes, it's coming directly from the above string url

Did you ever find a solution?
